# FMX TrackBar Control issue/bug?

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria, trackbar

Ok - I'm new to Delphi and FMX (been 30+ years since I've programmed in Pascal).
I've downloaded Delphi 11 Community Edition and have written approx 1800 lines of functional code since Friday night.
In my GUI - I added a FMX Trackbar. I've noticed that the Up/Down arrow keys appear to operate it in the reverse manner, i.e. UP arrow key decrements the value stored, the DOWN arrow key increments the value stored. This appears counter intuitive (for reference, LEFT arrow decrements and RIGHT arrow increments).  Is this a bug or intention? Any workarounds? If a bug, anyone have any ideas on how to get this resolved? I've attempted to rotate and the reverse the max and minimum values (as a work around - but this didn't work either, min can not be greater than max - which is logical but...)

I'm expecting that UP arrow would/should INCREMENT TrackBar.value and DOWN arrow would DECREMENT TrackBar.value, whether in vertical or horizontal orientations.

Comment: See answer [35002967](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35004576/2292722), but beware that the solution did not work on actual Android devices. I do not know what the situation is today.

Comment: Tom - Different question with a different solution. I want TrackBar.Value to decrement with LEFT arrow key AND DOWN arrow key and increment with RIGHT arrow key AND UP arrow key, but thanks for the suggestion. Perhaps if there was a way to disable one set of arrow keys (left/right or up/down) on the control then the .Value issue wouldn't be so much of an issue.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I was mislead by your last paragraph, thinking only about the UP and DOWN arrow keys. I will look into this again tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bug to me, but there's an easy workaround (which you'd have to remove if/when the bug gets fixed!).

Create an event handler for the `TTrackBar`'s `OnKeyDown` event, and put the following code in that event handler:

```
procedure TViewForm.TrackBar1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if key=vkUp   then key:=vkDown    else
  if key=vkDown then key:=vkUp;
end;
```

Go to https://quality.embarcadero.com/ to report this bug.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.